# how to get position of clicked item in OnClickListener of Listview?

Tags: android, listview

I want to get selected listview item onclicked listner of listview.

Right now I have implemented `onItemClickListener` but when I click on an item text then it is raised. I want to raise it on a listview row click.

Any idea how to achieve this? To get the text value of the list onClick listener?

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String value = lv1.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                //display value here 
                
                }
              });
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could use `lv1.getSelectedItemPosition()` OR `lv1.getSelectedItem()`

Answer (score 13):

Try using this code.

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {     ![enter image description here][2]
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          String value = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
               //display value here 
         }
});
```

Comment: no you never understand the question i am getting value using this function i want to achieve this functionality using onClick listener of listview

Comment: try to set a tag.

lv1.setTag(position)

and into onClick view.getTag()

Answer (score 4):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    int pos = parent.getPositionForView(view);
    Toast.makeText(this,pos + "",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Code only answers are usually not very useful unless they explain what they do.  This is very true of long segments of code.  Please consider adding an explanation of what you changed or wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If your ListView items were populated from an array **words** using an ArrayAdapter (which is hopefully) and implemented using a class **Word** with kind of this constructor:

```
public class Word {
    private String mValueA;
    /** Image resource ID for the word */
    private int mAudioResourceId;

    /*
    * Create a new Word object.
    */

    public Word(String valueA, int audioResourceId) {
        mValueA = valueA;
        mAudioResourceId = audioResourceId;
    }

   /*
    * Get the default translation of the word
     */
    public String getValueA() {
        return mValueA;
    }

    /**
     * Return the audio resource ID of the word.
     **/

    public int getAudioResourceId() {
        return mAudioResourceId;
    }    
}
```

And then you can set **setOnItemClickListener** to access clicked item for example to play audio defined in array for this list item.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        //like this:
        Word word = words.get(position);
        //and use this position to play the audio from the array
        //corresponding to its item
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(SomeActivity.this, word.getAudioResourceId());
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    int pos = (int) adapterView.getPositionForView(view);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need, by Kotlin:

```
tvSearchAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
   val item = cities.find { it.name == (view as TextView).text } ?: return@setOnItemClickListener
    // TODO item ....
}
```