# add second onclick to Listview

Tags: java, android

I want to add a second `on click` to a ListViewItem.
I already created the View (ImageView) and i set the on Click. The function gets called. 
But: How can i get the Informations of this ListViewItem? It would be enough to get the Position in the ListView?

The ImageView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:onClick="favorite"
    android:src="@drawable/star" />
```

The code for my on click function:

```
public void favorite(View view){
    ImageView iView = (ImageView) view;
    iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.star_checked);

    ViewParent v = iView.getParent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an anonymous inner class:

```
  ImageView iView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  iView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your code
            }
        });

myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {     ![enter image description here][2]

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String value = myListView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString(); // String value of the clicked item
                    //Code

                    }
                  });
```

If you want to make bigger applications you should think about better naming your components, 'imageView1' is not very handy. Name you components like 'imageview_main' or 'imageview_customerdetails'.

Comment: I have the onClickListener. But now i need to know on what ListViewItem this onClick was. But how can i get the position of the ListViewItem?

Comment: Just read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934552/how-to-get-position-of-clicked-item-in-onclicklistener-of-listview, you can now use the integer 'position'

Comment: I think you missunderstood what i mean. I have the ListView. Every item have one onItemClick Event. But in every ListViewItem is one ImageView. This ImageView shoudl have another, different OnItemClick. But: How?

Comment: You'll have to add each ImageView in an ArrayList. When the ListView is clicked you can get the position of the clicked ImageView with the code in my post. Do not add a Listener to both the ListView and the ImageView, weird thing will happen

Answer (score 0):

Subclass [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) rather than OnClickListener.

Edit:

Okay I think I understand what you are trying to do now. I would subclass your ListAdapter and override the `getView(int position, ...)` method like so:

```
private OnClickListener mImgClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
            // do stuff with position knowledge!
        }
    });

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView != null) {
        v = convertView;
    } else {
        v = newView(int position);
    }
    v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setTag(position);
    return v;
}

private View newView(int position) {
    View v;
    // inflate your view here
    View imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(mImgClickListener);
    return v;
}
```

Of course, even better would be to implement the ViewHolder pattern in the getView method to eliminate expensive calls to `findViewById`.

I believe the View hierarchy will take care of giving priority to the click on the ImageView (rather than the list item as a whole), but I could be wrong.