# How to read and update SQLite database using ListView in Android?

Tags: java, android, database, eclipse, android-sqlite

I've been doing research in the internet for 15-20 hours and can't find the answer to this question yet "How to read and update SQLite database using ListView in Android?" in other words how do you make the ListView Items Intent to the saved data in the SQLite Database and how to update them once you get to the other activity. I have tried many different ways to do this and so far they either don't work or crash my application. Can someone please help or at least lead me to the right direction, thank you.

activity_main_activity_planes.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivityPlanes" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/add_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main_activity_paper.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivityPaper" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/save_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/update_button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >
</EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivityPlanes.java

```
public class MainActivityPlanes extends Activity {

Button Add;
ListView List;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_planes);

    Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
        {           
        Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this, MainActivityChampagne.class);
        startActivity(launchActivity);
    }
});

    Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {

        public void onClick (View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivityPaper.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

    MainActivityChampagne info = new MainActivityChampagne(this);       
    info.open();        
    ArrayList<String> data = info.getData();
    info.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    List.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

}
```

MainActivityPaper.java

```
public class MainActivityPaper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView text1, title1;
Button save1, update1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_paper);

    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    save1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    update1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    save1.setOnClickListener(this);
    update1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.button3:

        String titles = title1.getText().toString();
        String notes = text1.getText().toString();

        MainActivityChampagne entry = new MainActivityChampagne(MainActivityPaper.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(titles, notes);
        entry.close();

        break;

    case R.id.button5:

        String thetitles = title1.getText().toString();
        String thenotes = text1.getText().toString();

        MainActivityChampagne up = new MainActivityChampagne(MainActivityPaper.this);
        up.open();
        up.updateEntry(thetitles, thenotes);
        up.close();

        break;

    }

}

}
```

MainActivityChampagne.java

```
public class MainActivityChampagne {

public static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
public static final String KEY_NOTES = "lastcall";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Champagnedb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "champagneTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub\
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public MainActivityChampagne(Context c){
    ourContext = c;

}

public MainActivityChampagne open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();

}

public long createEntry(String titles, String notes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, titles);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public ArrayList<String> getData() {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";
    int iNotes = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    ArrayList<String> string_array = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
    result = c.getString (iNotes) + "\n";
    string_array.add(result);
    }
           return string_array;

}

public void updateEntry(String thetitles, String thenotes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, thetitles);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NOTES, thenotes);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=" + thetitles + KEY_NOTES + "=" + thenotes, null);

}

}
```

LogCat

```
06-21 03:42:16.782: E/Trace(3639): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-21 03:42:18.622: D/dalvikvm(3639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 46K, 7% free 2545K/2712K, paused 440ms, total 444ms
06-21 03:42:18.715: I/dalvikvm-heap(3639): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.673MB for 1127536-byte allocation
06-21 03:42:19.022: D/dalvikvm(3639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3645K/3816K, paused 308ms, total 308ms
06-21 03:42:19.312: D/dalvikvm(3639): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3651K/3816K, paused 18ms+15ms, total 290ms
06-21 03:42:20.582: I/Choreographer(3639): Skipped 65 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 03:42:20.752: D/gralloc_goldfish(3639): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-21 03:42:21.352: I/Choreographer(3639): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 03:42:24.841: D/dalvikvm(3639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 25K, 4% free 3984K/4132K, paused 67ms, total 95ms
06-21 03:42:24.941: D/dalvikvm(3639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 4% free 4238K/4400K, paused 61ms, total 67ms
06-21 03:42:25.081: D/dalvikvm(3639): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 4766K/4936K, paused 74ms+6ms, total 124ms
06-21 03:42:25.094: D/dalvikvm(3639): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 37ms
06-21 03:42:25.193: D/dalvikvm(3639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 5294K/5472K, paused 57ms, total 57ms
06-21 03:42:25.293: D/dalvikvm(3639): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 6086K/6276K, paused 57ms, total 57ms
06-21 03:42:25.453: I/Choreographer(3639): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 03:42:32.381: D/AndroidRuntime(3639): Shutting down VM
06-21 03:42:32.401: W/dalvikvm(3639): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {android.application.project.planes/android.application.project.planes.MainActivityChampagne}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.application.project.planes.MainActivityPlanes$1.onItemClick(MainActivityPlanes.java:36)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-21 03:42:32.461: E/AndroidRuntime(3639):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 03:42:35.471: I/Process(3639): Sending signal. PID: 3639 SIG: 9
06-21 03:43:13.141: D/dalvikvm(3658): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 7% free 2545K/2716K, paused 229ms, total 232ms
06-21 03:43:13.161: I/dalvikvm-heap(3658): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.673MB for 1127536-byte allocation
06-21 03:43:13.241: D/dalvikvm(3658): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3645K/3820K, paused 74ms, total 74ms
06-21 03:43:13.391: D/dalvikvm(3658): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3645K/3820K, paused 10ms+4ms, total 152ms
06-21 03:43:14.711: I/Choreographer(3658): Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-21 03:43:14.852: D/gralloc_goldfish(3658): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-21 03:43:19.123: D/AndroidRuntime(3658): Shutting down VM
06-21 03:43:19.131: W/dalvikvm(3658): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {android.application.project.planes/android.application.project.planes.MainActivityChampagne}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.application.project.planes.MainActivityPlanes$1.onItemClick(MainActivityPlanes.java:36)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-21 03:43:19.181: E/AndroidRuntime(3658):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 03:43:24.262: I/Process(3658): Sending signal. PID: 3658 SIG: 9
```

ProjectPlanes Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android.application.project.planes"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="android.application.project.planes.MainActivityPlanes"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="android.application.project.planes.MainActivityPaper"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Updated LogCat

```
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 05:12:19.072: I/Process(4313): Sending signal. PID: 4313 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The cause of the crash is right there in the log: `Unable to find explicit activity class {android.application.project.planes/android.application.project.planes.MainActivityChampagne}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: @Karakuri If you remove the OnItemClickListener in MainActivityPlanes it'll work but thats my question how to fix this?

Comment: @user2507499 use  need to get the data from the data base and set the data to the listview.

Comment: @user2507499 try my answer and inform if it works.

Comment: you still have this  `Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this, MainActivityChampagne.class);
        startActivity(launchActivity)`. remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Is Your Edited Working Code

MainActivityChampagne.java

```
package android.application.project.planes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MainActivityChampagne {

    public static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
    public static final String KEY_NOTES = "lastcall";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Champagnedb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "champagneTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub\
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_NAME
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);

        }

    }

    public MainActivityChampagne(Context c) {
        ourContext = c;

    }

    public MainActivityChampagne open() {
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

    }

    public void close() {
        ourHelper.close();

    }

    public long createEntry(String titles, String notes) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, titles);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        String result = "";
        int iNotes = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        ArrayList<String> string_array = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            result = c.getString(iNotes) + "\n";
            string_array.add(result);
        }
        return string_array;

    }

    public void updateEntry(String thetitles, String thenotes) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
        cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, thetitles);
        /* cvUpdate.put(KEY_NOTES, thenotes); */
        /*
         * ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=" +
         * thetitles + KEY_NOTES + "=" + thenotes, null);
         */
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "='"
                + thetitles + "'", null);

    }

}
```

MainActivityPaper.java

```
package android.application.project.planes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivityPaper extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView text1, title1;
    Button save1, update1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_paper);

        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        save1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        update1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        save1.setOnClickListener(this);
        update1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.button3:

            String titles = title1.getText().toString();
            String notes = text1.getText().toString();

            MainActivityChampagne entry = new MainActivityChampagne(
                    MainActivityPaper.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(titles, notes);
            entry.close();

            break;

        case R.id.button5:

            String thetitles = title1.getText().toString();
            String thenotes = text1.getText().toString();

            MainActivityChampagne up = new MainActivityChampagne(
                    MainActivityPaper.this);
            up.open();
            up.updateEntry(thetitles, thenotes);
            up.close();

            break;

        }

    }

}
```

MainActivityPlanes.java

```
package android.application.project.planes;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivityPlanes extends Activity {

    Button Add;
    ListView List;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_planes);

        Add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this,
                        MainActivityPaper.class);
                startActivity(launchActivity);
            }
        });

        Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivityPaper.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        MainActivityChampagne info = new MainActivityChampagne(this);
        info.open();
        ArrayList<String> data = info.getData();
        info.close();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        List.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }

}
```

Here What is wrong in your code is SQLite Database queries. You are created only on row in that table and trying to compare two values while updating. You just check you code you will be able to modify according to that.
Hope this will help.

Add the Following code to make your list-view on-click working

Add the following code in MainActivityPlanes.java

```
        List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            String str1 = List.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            System.out.println(str1);
            Bundle bucket = new Bundle();
            bucket.putString("my_key", str1);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this,
                    MainActivityPaper.class);
            launchActivity.putExtras(bucket);
            startActivity(launchActivity);
        }
    });
```

Add the Following code in MainActivityPaper.java

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_paper);


    text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    String s = null;
    try{
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        s= b.getString("my_key");

        }catch(Exception e){
            s="";
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            text1.setText(s.toString());
        }
    title1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    save1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    update1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    save1.setOnClickListener(this);
    update1.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: The code is Ace but the only problem is when it takes me to the saved data, ???nothings there??? it also no longer lets me create and updating still doesn't work, why is this?

Comment: Whatever you are doing in OnItemClick() is Wrong. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934552/how-to-get-position-of-clicked-item-in-onclicklistener-of-listview and use bundle with intent to pass data to another activity and set it from there i think this will help

Comment: Here in your code you are simple redirecting it to MainActivityPaper.class You just get the clicked item in that code and Attach it to intent using bundle. This will solve your problem

Comment: @Aadi your code does not populate listview with items. where is the code that populates the listview with data from data base?

Comment: @Raghunandan you just try to run my code then you will get list-view that populates data from database.

Comment: @Aadi it does not work for me can you post a snap shot by testing it on emulator or device?

Comment: @Aadi it does display the data from list items but it does not update the data in the data base

Comment: @Aadi op does not have a column `KEY_NOTES` in the create table query.

Comment: @Raghunandan Yes, I already mentioned that Query is wrong in SQLite database he didn't create row for KEY_NOTES so i also programmed according to that. I just wanted to show how this can be done that's it.

Comment: @Raghunandan You just check the SQL Query that he did, I make that code working if he has to update he has to create table properly and write the query according to that

Answer (score 1):

This should be removed.

```
Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this, MainActivityChampagne.class);
startActivity(launchActivity);
```

And you have this

```
 public class MainActivityChampagne
```

Your `MainActivityChampagne`  class does not extend activity. It's a non activity class.

To set data to listview.

```
 MainActivityChampagne db = new MainActivityChampagne(MainActivityPlanes.this);
 db.open();
 ArrayList<String> list = db.getData();
```

Now use the list to set the data to listview.

Define row.xml with a textview with id textView1.

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivityPlanes.this, R.layout.row, R.id.textView1,list);  
  List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
  List.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Once you set the adapter to listview.

```
 List.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
  {           
        .  // on list item click do what is necessary
  }
  });
```

Edit:

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="114dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap shot

[image]

Edit2 : The update is fixed. However you need to modify the below according to your needs.

```
public class MainActivityChampagne {

public static final String KEY_NAME = "title";
public static final String KEY_NOTES = "lastcall";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Champagnedb5";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "champagneTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub\
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + 
                KEY_NOTES + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ");"
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

}

public MainActivityChampagne(Context c){
    ourContext = c;

}

public MainActivityChampagne open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();

}

public long createEntry(String titles, String notes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, titles);
    cv.put(KEY_NOTES, notes);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public ArrayList<String> getData() {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";
    int iNotes = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    ArrayList<String> string_array = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
    result = c.getString (iNotes) + "\n";
    string_array.add(result);
    }
           return string_array;

}

public void updateEntry(String thetitles, String thenotes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cvUpdate = new ContentValues();
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NAME, thetitles);
    cvUpdate.put(KEY_NOTES, thenotes);
    ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, "id "+"="+1, null);
    // this will update row 1 coz id is 1. 
    //ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cvUpdate, KEY_NAME + "=" + thetitles + KEY_NOTES + "=" + thenotes, null);

}

}
```

Comment: My application keeps crashing right when it starts now. The LogCat saids...06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
06-21 05:12:14.752: E/AndroidRuntime(4313):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)

Comment: did you try the above?. if so post the update code and logcat details of the crash

Comment: this is wrong  `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);`. you have not done as mentioned in the post. also post the full stack trace by editing your question

Comment: move this `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` below  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_paper)` and try

Comment: MainActivityChampagne db = new MainActivityChampagne(MainActivityPlanes.this);
        db.open();
        ArrayList<String> list = db.getData();
        db.close();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivityPlanes.this, R.layout.activity_main_activity_planes, R.id.editText1,list);  
        List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
        List.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: wrong again. define row.xml in your layout resource file. have a textview with is textView1 and use the above.

Comment: you want me to make a new layout names row? and then add it like the example you gave me?

Comment: with a root element of EditText or ListView?

Comment: so I created it and built it like the sample you recently posted and it still crashes the app.

Comment: the above should work if you do it right. i guess you are doing something wrong

Comment: the markers mark 0 mistakes and the code given from you seems like it should work but now it crashes as soon as the application opens.

Comment: you still have this `Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivityPlanes.this, MainActivityChampagne.class);
        startActivity(launchActivity)` remove it

Comment: the code given by Aadi worked except it no longer lets me create, still wont update, and when I'm taken to an items saved data nothing there.

Comment: I did remove it also the app has always been able to create with the code I first posted just the update and OnItemClick crashed the app

Comment: it works for me your update query is wrong. i don't know how to help you further. i can't waste my time on this. but i can say except for the update the code works for me

Comment: me too I was going to say the created items i made 10ish minutes ago were just created idk why it took that long (I'm using an AVD, don't know if it has to do with that) but It still doesn't want to Intent to the data it should have and also the update.

Comment: where is your `KEY_NOTES` column while creating table. your create query does not have the column mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Answering a question you didn't ask yet, but causing one of your problems is a missing declaration of MainActivityChampagne in your manifest. Needless to say, the crash log is correct (text search your manifest for "MainActivityChampagne" and you have zero hits).

[image]

Comment: I just added it works the same, is there a reason it needs to be there?

Comment: I know you know this, because you're smart and you've read the manual before starting in ernest so I apologise for having to answer: "You must declare your activity in the manifest file in order for it to be accessible to the system." from http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Declaring. Not doing this will result in a crash when you try to start your activity. That should be reason enough.

Comment: so any activity made in a project should be put in the android manifest even if its used as an sql database class?

Comment: Like the docs say - and you've undoubtedly been shrewd enough to read the introduction to the `Activity` class and more before starting - and like your crash log is screaming at you in the face, yes _every_ `Activity` you use must be declared in the manifest.

Comment: @SK9 `public class MainActivityChampagne {` does not extend activity its a non activity class.

Comment: You're trying to start a non-activity as though it's an Activity: `MainActivityChampagne` doesn't extend `Activity`. The second parameter of the `Intent` constructor you're calling should be an `Activity` class, but your `MainActivityChampagne` doesn't extend `Activity`. Because of your `startActivity` call, the system is going to the manifest to find an `Activity` which has no chance of being there. You're making at least two gaffes here. You need to decide what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Raghunandan Correct. Why is there an Intent construction followed by startActivity call? There seem to be at least two mistakes.

Comment: @SK9 also his database does not have a column `KEY_NOTE`. check the create table query. he needs to add the column as well

Comment: @Raghunandan At least three mistakes, and counting. I'm not going to check his table for him, that's his problem :)

Comment: @SK9 yup you are right. too many mistakes and its like we will have to code for him. but who is going to do that. no body is going to waste a lot of time on this.

Comment: "I just added it works the same, is there a reason it needs to be there?" I think we can stop here.

Comment: I added it to manifest also if i extend it, it marks mostly the entire class wrong.